# how to add exception to avoid duplicate insert in trigger

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_SHUBH_TR9_Triggerr
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON TEST_SHUBH_TR9
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF UPDATING
    THEN
      INSERT INTO TEST_SHUBH_TR9_REF (NEW_FIRST_NAME,OLD_FIRST_NAME,NEW_LAST_NAME,OLD_LAST_NAME,NEW_ADDRESS,OLD_ADDRESS,NEW_SRNO,OLD_SRNO,NEW_JOB_TITLE,OLD_JOB_TITLE, NEW_UPDATETIME,OLD_UPDATETIME, OPERATION)
      VALUES(:NEW.FIRST_NAME,:OLD.FIRST_NAME,:NEW.LAST_NAME,:OLD.LAST_NAME,:NEW.ADDRESS,:OLD.ADDRESS,:NEW.SRNO,:OLD.SRNO,:NEW.JOB_TITLE,:OLD.JOB_TITLE,:NEW.UPDATETIME,:OLD.UPDATETIME,'update');         
    END IF;
    IF INSERTING
    THEN
      INSERT INTO TEST_SHUBH_TR9_REF(NEW_SRNO,NEW_FIRST_NAME,NEW_LAST_NAME,NEW_ADDRESS,NEW_JOB_TITLE,NEW_UPDATETIME,OPERATION)
      VALUES(:NEW.SRNO, :NEW.FIRST_NAME, :NEW.LAST_NAME,:NEW.ADDRESS,:NEW.JOB_TITLE,:NEW.UPDATETIME,'insert');
    END IF;
    IF DELETING
    THEN
      INSERT INTO TEST_SHUBH_TR9_REF(OLD_SRNO,OLD_FIRST_NAME,OLD_LAST_NAME,OLD_ADDRESS,OLD_JOB_TITLE,OLD_UPDATETIME,OPERATION)
      VALUES(:OLD.srno, :OLD.FIRST_NAME,:OLD.LAST_NAME,:OLD.ADDRESS,:OLD.JOB_TITLE,:OLD.UPDATETIME,'delete');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Duplication of what column(s)? No need to use a trigger for such an aim, but just add a unique key such as `ALTER TABLE test_shubh_tr9 ADD CONSTRAINT uk_test_shubh_tr9 UNIQUE(srno first_name, last_name);` for the uniqueness should depend on the first three columns as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Code you posted looks like a *logging* trigger. If that's so, why do you mind there are duplicates? You're logging *everything*, aren't you? I'd leave it *as is*.

---

Anyway, you never said what "duplicate" it is, so I presumed - for simplicity - it is the `SRNO` column. In that case, switch from `VALUES` to a *dummy* `SELECT` statement (as it selects from `dual`). Why? So that you could use `NOT EXISTS`.

If there are other columns involved in that "uniqueness" thing, just add those columns into subquerie's `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
WHERE a.srno = :new.srno
  AND a.first_name = :new.first_name
  AND a.last_name  = :new.last_name
```

OK, here's the trigger (just a part of it; you'd modify the rest as well).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_shubh_tr9_triggerr AFTER
  INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON test_shubh_tr9
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF updating THEN
    INSERT INTO test_shubh_tr9_ref(
      new_srno,
      new_first_name,
      old_first_name,
      new_last_name,
      old_last_name,
      new_address,
      old_address,
      new_srno,
      old_srno,
      new_job_title,
      old_job_title,
      new_updatetime,
      old_updatetime,
      operation
    )
    SELECT
      :new.srno,
      :new.first_name,
      :old.first_name,
      :new.last_name,
      :old.last_name,
      :new.address,
      :old.address,
      :new.srno,
      :old.srno,
      :new.job_title,
      :old.job_title,
      :new.updatetime,
      :old.updatetime,
      'update'
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                      FROM test_shubh_tr9_ref a
                      WHERE a.srno = :new.srno
                     );
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: i don't have the primary key  in my table test_shubh_tr9

Comment: I never said you do.

Comment: but if i insert same record into the test_shubh_tr9 , it is inserted into my reference table same record two times (created table for handling the insert record)

Comment: So read what's been said. You have to know which columns are responsible to enforce uniqueness you're talking about, so you'll have to put all of them into the WHERE clause.

Comment: how to modify trigger then?